# Button Click Event..Odoo8

Tags: odoo

I have a button named as action_list and it is placed in XML file and works ok. What I want is that I want to fetch data from my table like task_name and duration on button click and this should be displayed in a new wizard where target =new. Am trying the below code. please guide me in all cases

```
def action_list(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):

    cr.execute("SELECT task_name, duration FROM activity_track WHERE id =%s",ids)

    result= map(lambda x: x[0], cr.fetchall())


    return {

      'type':'ir.actions.act_window',

      'view_mode':'tree,form',

      'view_type':'tree',

      'domain':'[]',

      'nodestroy': True,

       'target': 'new',

      'res_model':'activity.track',

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by 2 ways

1./ Either you can pass the 'result' in the context, and you pass that context in your action along with other parameters like domain,target. Then you can get that value in your wizard from context variable

```
 def action_list(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):

    cr.execute("SELECT task_name, duration FROM activity_track WHERE id =%s",ids)

    result= map(lambda x: x[0], cr.fetchall())

    context.update({myresult':result})

    return {

      'type':'ir.actions.act_window',

      'view_mode':'tree,form',

      'view_type':'tree',

      'domain':'[]',

      'nodestroy': True,

      'context':context,

       'target': 'new',

      'res_model':'activity.track',


        }
```

2./ In your wizard you get the 'active_ids', using this you can get the result directly in the wizard itself. active_ids will the ids same as which are passed in the button click event that you are trying to use. Following line will be used in the wizard.

`current_ids =context.get('active_ids',False)`

Comment: Thanks Hardik

Is this a comment? **'context':context,**

You mean to wrote this? context.update({myresult:'result'})

Thanks again

Comment: Hardik. I am finally getting a wizard..But..This wizard is showing me list view of current entered values. I already have values in table. I want to show and fetch those values and show on front end?

Thanks

Comment: I should have a table displayed in front end of Odoo showing all values... Below code is showing me list view of my current entered values. 
Thanks

Comment: This sounds confusing, I am not getting actually which values you want to show it on the wizard. What you have to do is as soon as get the 'active_ids' in wizard code, you can perform the same thing that you have done in the click event of the button. You can execute the same query that you have executed in the button click. The thing is you just have to do that processing here instead of in the button click. For performing this operation try to find the example of wizard have defined the method 'default_get'. In this method you have to perform your operation.

Comment: I tel you.. My database has a table named as activity_track .. By this table I want to get all values as a list in front end. LIke in format we have similar to Microsoft word table showing on front end...